# How to create new profile for Firefox through python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, geckodriver

**Why?**
I've been trying to learn automation for the last week since I thought it would be easier to do my job. right now I am working on configuring web browsers. There are other things I need to do but for now I'm working on the browser side. almost daily I have to set up user profiles and sometimes 10 at a time doing the same thing over and over. So I thought 'Why not just make a program that does all this for me?'

**Goal**
I want to create a new profile for Firefox from python, I just want this to be as close as a run code and let everything set up on its own. 
I would like that profile to have a default homepage.

That's it. I honestly had an easier time doing this on chrome mines the creating a new profile, but from what I read I need a new profile with Firefox.

Can anyone help me out, I would appreciate any guidance.